# String manipulation with apply function

Tags: python, apply

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'desc':['A70-11370; reprint; rolled; 2000; 26.5; 38.5',
 'A70-713; reprint; rolled; 26.5; 38.5',
 'b70-7814; reprint; style a; rolled; 1939; 22.5; 34.5',
 'A70-7600; reprint; rolled; 26.5; 38.5']})

df
```

I'm trying to extract the 4 digit year (eg. 2000) like this:

```
df['year'] = df['desc'].apply(lambda x: x.strip() if str(x).strip().isnumeric() else np.nan for x in x.split(';'))
```

But I'm getting this - NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Comment: You are getting the error because you use 'x' to mean two different things in your lambda function: it is both the variable of the lambda and the variable of the for statement. Because your function is complicated agood approach is to define it separately and then `apply` it to the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is extract the year, then you can simply do this:

```
df['year'] = df['desc'].str.extract(r'\b(19\d{2}|20\d{2})\b')
```

The above code assumes:

- your years are between 1900 and 2099. (If that's not the case then you need to modify the regex.)
- there are no non-year numbers that look like years. (Any number between 1900 and 2099 will be interpreted as a year, whether it's actually a year or not.)

If there are multiple year-like numbers in a cell, only the first one will be returned.

Comment: like how concise this is. regex is still a pain point for me @ba_μL

Comment: I'm using regexr.com. So I tried extracting the decimal numbers into columns x and y in a similar way: ```df['x'] = df['desc'].str.extract(r'.(\d+\.\d+).')``` gives 26.5. However, I get the same value when I try for the next number. I want 38.5 @ba_ul

Comment: To capture the decismals, assuming there are only two in a cell: 
`df[['x','y']] = df['desc'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+\.\d+)\b.*\b(\d+\.\d+)\b')`

Comment: I really must improve my regex. Works a treat.@ba_μL